# There is a CSS Error on WordPress font-family: "

Tags: css, wordpress

[Screenshot of CSS Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r462X.png)I would like to save some changes I made to a CSS on WordPress but before I can save there's an error that has to be addressed. "There is 1 error which must be fixed before you can save."

I can see where the error is and there's an exclamation point next to line 9 where there is font-family: ". 
When I hover over this error it further states: `Unexpected token ' " font-size 14px; ' at line 9, col 15.`

What does it mean by unexpected token and what do I need to fix?

I am new at this and I am not sure who worked on this previously. Trying to figure this out without destroying my employers website. Would appreciate any help, thank you!

```
m input[type=submit] {
    width: auto;
    font-family: "
    font-size: 14px;
    height: auto;
    line-height: normal;
```

Comment: You dont have any font-family value which is probably resulting in error

Comment: Yup, that was the issue. I added "Open Sans"; and that got rid of the error. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Are you missing a closing quotation after `normal`?

Comment: If I add a closing quotation after that it and creates another error message. I have edited the post and attached a screenshot of what I am looking at, maybe that will help clarify? Thanks

Comment: @Lema looks like you have multiple sets of quotes in the wrong places. I would review your CSS for improper placement of quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You dont have any font-family value which is probably resulting in error

m input[type=submit] { width: auto; font-family: "Missing_value" font-size: 14px; height: auto; line-height: normal;

Answer (score 0):

Unexpected token means something that does not belong or cannot be read as a value for the css property you are trying to set. You have `font-family:"` and in this case `"` isn't a valid value for the property `font-family` because it expects (1) a font-family name (e.g. 'helvetica') and (2) because you haven't closed the property with `;`